# HTML Menu set Parent item class if child item has class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML menu that has `.active` classes.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-left" id="navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="/account-details">Account Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contacts/contacts">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The `active` classes are set on the `<li>` items (parent and sub items)

How can I use javascript to set the active class on the items if the url equals the `href` of the menu item and also set its parent item with the active class

I tried to do it with this javascript, but it didn't work.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#navbar-collapse li').each(function() {
      if(this.href.indexOf(window.location.pathname) === 0) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      } else {
        // case when something was set to active by the server
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(document.querySelector('.dropdown .active')
   document.querySelector('.dropdown').classList.add('active');
```

Basically, if any `<li>` child has class `.active`, then assign `.active` to the `.dropdown` element

Edit: [working example](http://codepen.io/hawking/pen/BQPgVa)

Comment: have a look at my update, i missed of adding the active class to the child items

Comment: @charlie, so you want to apply `.active` to all other `<li>`?

Comment: @charlie, okay, I know what you're trying to do

Comment: yes what you have written in your answer is what I want to do but I want to also add in, if the current page is equal to the href of an item then add the active class to it

Comment: try changing selector to `$('#navbar-collapse li a')` in your code, because you weren't checking for `href` in `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Use this: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
$('li.active').closest('li').addClass('active');
```